# using asp.net mvc3 with jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js to validate form and changebutton

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I am working with mvc3 and use model validation like this:

```
    public class ColumnVM {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }}
```

I want to do clientside validation with model validation.
My html is :

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddColumn","Column",FormMethod.Post))
@html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Name)
<input type="submit" value="submit" style="background-color:blue">
```

I want to do the client validation before submit.If the submit is valid,the submitbutton change its color and disbled itself calling:`function changeBtnColor(obj) {
    obj.css("background-color", "#A9A9A9");
    obj.attr("disabled", "disabled");
}`
If not,do not change its color and do not disable,and show validation error message.
When  jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js is in,I cannot use $("form").validate() any more. How can I do this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this script after the jquery, jquery validate and jquery validate unobtrusive scripts

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("form").validate().settings.submitHandler = function (form) {
            alert('valid form');
            // do your stuff here
            form.submit();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `submitHandler` already submits the form, so `form.submit()` is superfluous, unless there's something about `unobtrusive` that requires it.

Comment: the validate method is no use. The error is "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate' ".

Comment: @user carefully double check that your scripts are included and in the right order if $("form") has no method 'validate' then no validation will be taking place